# autocomplete with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page with a search box, if I manual copy/paste a word or just a part of it the search box will extend to an auto-complete box with few possible search options. If I use to access that page trough python and selenium the same way:

```
city = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='my_search_box_imput']")
city.click()
city.clear()
city.send_keys(some_value)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

This works fine BUT auto-complete box will not appear after city.send_keys(some_value).
I tried to use special keys for selenium as well:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

city = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='my_search_box_imput']")
city.click()
city.clear()
city.send_keys(some_value)
city.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') #highlight all in box
city.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') #copy
city.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v') #paste    
city.send_keys(some_value)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

But in this situation I am getting an error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element not     found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up' ; Stacktrace:
        at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:8180:5)
        at Utils.getElementAt (file:///c:/users/jane/appdata/local/temp/tmpamb_no/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7783:3)
        at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/jane/appdata/local/temp/tmpamb_no/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8789:1)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///c:/users/jane/appdata/local/temp/tmpamb_no/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11438:1)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/jane/appdata/local/temp/tmpamb_no/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455:11)
        at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///c:/users/jane/appdata/local/temp/tmpamb_no/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:407:5)
```

I didn't manage to find any solution so far I wonder if somebody with python/selenium experience can post an advice. Thanks!

I am using pyhton 2.7 on windows 7 and firefox webdriver.

Comment: I tried the following code on wikipedia and it worked:             'driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
search_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
search_elem.clear()
search_elem.send_keys('a')'

Comment: Thanks for comment, I tried the same code as example, worked for me to...as a fact of matter my code works too :) I used to carry a '\n' in my 'some_value' string which produced the problem that I had. rstrip('some_value') fixed it.